# Uploading Files to Github from a Local Repo

Tags: xcode4, github

I have a Xcode 4 project, and when I opened it in the first time I did checked the "create a local respo for the project...". I also have a repo in GitHub. How to upload the files from my computer to the repo in github?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

initialize your local folder as a git repo:

```
git init
```

stage your local files in the repo

```
git add .
```

commit your code to the repo

```
git commit -m 'comment'
```

tell git about your remote repo

```
git remote add origin //your github conneciton here
```

push your local master branch to the "origin" remote repo

```
git push origin master
```